# should a glass fixed panel shower door sit directly on a tile curb?

Tags: bathroom, shower, remodeling, sliding-glass-door

Should a glass fixed panel shower door sit directly on a tile curb? Instructions that I have don't say anything about having a small gap. I would think a small gap, say 1/8" would allow for silicone caulk. Also, I thought that tempered glass should not touch tile. (This is the fixed portion of a sliding glass door.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, I don't think it's a good idea for it to have any direct contact with the tile. So if you are not using a U-channel to mount it, then spacing it with some shims should work fine. And yes,, I wouldn't space it beyond 1/8".
When you are caulking the edges, try to leave the shims in and caulk over it. But cut them so that it's hidden beneath the caulking.
I assume you will be using clear silicone?
If you can get ahold of clear shims, that would be ideal.